# Percentile Distribution Graph

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Does anyone have an idea how to change X axis scale and ticks to display a percentile distribution like the graph below?  This image is from MATLAB, but I want to use Python (via Matplotlib or Seaborn) to generate.

[image: Graph of distribution where there is lots of change >99%]

From the pointer by @paulh, I'm a lot closer now.  This code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import probscale
import seaborn as sns

clear_bkgd = {'axes.facecolor':'none', 'figure.facecolor':'none'}
sns.set(style='ticks', context='notebook', palette="muted", rc=clear_bkgd)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

x = [30, 60, 80, 90, 95, 97, 98, 98.5, 98.9, 99.1, 99.2, 99.3, 99.4]
y = np.arange(0, 12.1, 1)

ax.set_xlim(40, 99.5)
ax.set_xscale('prob')

ax.plot(x, y)
sns.despine(fig=fig)
```

Generates the following plot (notice the re-distributed X-Axis)

[image: Graph with non-linear x-axis]

Which I find much more useful than a the standard scale:

[image: Graph with normal x-axis]

I contacted the author of the original graph and they gave me some pointers.  It is actually a log scale graph, with x axis reversed and values of [100-val], with manual labeling of the x axis ticks.  The code below recreates the original image with the same sample data as the other graphs here.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

clear_bkgd = {'axes.facecolor':'none', 'figure.facecolor':'none'}
sns.set(style='ticks', context='notebook', palette="muted", rc=clear_bkgd)

x = [30, 60, 80, 90, 95, 97, 98, 98.5, 98.9, 99.1, 99.2, 99.3, 99.4]
y = np.arange(0, 12.1, 1)

# Number of intervals to display.
# Later calculations add 2 to this number to pad it to align with the reversed axis
num_intervals = 3
x_values = 1.0 - 1.0/10**np.arange(0,num_intervals+2)

# Start with hard-coded lengths for 0,90,99
# Rest of array generated to display correct number of decimal places as precision increases
lengths = [1,2,2] + [int(v)+1 for v in list(np.arange(3,num_intervals+2))]

# Build the label string by trimming on the calculated lengths and appending %
labels = [str(100*v)[0:l] + "%" for v,l in zip(x_values, lengths)]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
# Labels have to be reversed because axis is reversed
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels( labels[::-1] )

ax.plot([100.0 - v for v in x], y)

ax.grid(True, linewidth=0.5, zorder=5)
ax.grid(True, which='minor', linewidth=0.5, linestyle=':')

sns.despine(fig=fig)

plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300, format='png')
```

This is the resulting graph:
[image: Graph with "inverted log scale"]

Comment: Have you written any code or put any effort into doing this yourself? If so, please post here.

Comment: I do in no way understand why this question was closed as *too broad*. Although it lacks a good problem description, the problem itself becomes apparent from looking at the graph.  If there was a way to produce this kind of graph, it would surely only take a couple of code lines, so an answer would neither be too long nor would one expect there to be too many possible answers.

Comment: @Chris Osterwood Please provide the matlab command that produces this kind of graph and also supply a clear problem description in text form, not only by posting a picture. You can do so by posting them as comment, such that more experienced users can incorporate them into the question.

Comment: I think you want to use on my libraries: http://phobson.github.io/mpl-probscale/

Comment: @PaulH  - thanks so much!  I've edited my question with code using mpl-probscale and it's MUCH closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChrisOsterwood so does that resolve your problem or is there still a question to be answered?

Comment: @PaulH It nearly did, I contact the author of the original graph and they pointed me in the correct direction (log plot with x axis reversed and manual labeling of ticks).  My question has been modified with code showing how to do this in python.

Answer (score 3):

The following Python code uses [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) to read a csv file that contains a list of recorded latency values (in milliseconds), then it records those latency values (as microseconds) in an [HdrHistogram](https://pypi.org/project/hdrhistogram/), and saves the HdrHistogram to an [hgrm](https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram_py/blob/6462abfaf4b1557769e366ea620ad94f51fbc605/hdrh/histogram.py#L597) file, that will then be used by [Seaborn](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/) to [plot](https://hdrhistogram.github.io/HdrHistogram/plotFiles.html) the latency distribution graph.

```
import pandas as pd
from hdrh.histogram import HdrHistogram
from hdrh.dump import dump
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import sys
import argparse

# Parse the command line arguments.

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('csv_file')
parser.add_argument('hgrm_file')
parser.add_argument('png_file')
args = parser.parse_args()

csv_file = args.csv_file
hgrm_file = args.hgrm_file
png_file = args.png_file

# Read the csv file into a Pandas data frame and generate an hgrm file.

csv_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=False)

USECS_PER_SEC=1000000
MIN_LATENCY_USECS = 1
MAX_LATENCY_USECS = 24 * 60 * 60 * USECS_PER_SEC # 24 hours
# MAX_LATENCY_USECS = int(csv_df['response-time'].max()) * USECS_PER_SEC # 1 hour
LATENCY_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS = 5
histogram = HdrHistogram(MIN_LATENCY_USECS, MAX_LATENCY_USECS, LATENCY_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS)
for latency_sec in csv_df['response-time'].tolist():
    histogram.record_value(latency_sec*USECS_PER_SEC)
    # histogram.record_corrected_value(latency_sec*USECS_PER_SEC, 10)
TICKS_PER_HALF_DISTANCE=5
histogram.output_percentile_distribution(open(hgrm_file, 'wb'), USECS_PER_SEC, TICKS_PER_HALF_DISTANCE)

# Read the generated hgrm file into a Pandas data frame.

hgrm_df = pd.read_csv(hgrm_file, comment='#', skip_blank_lines=True, sep=r"\s+", engine='python', header=0, names=['Latency', 'Percentile'], usecols=[0, 3])

# Plot the latency distribution using Seaborn and save it as a png file.

sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style("dark")
sns.set_context("paper")
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,15))
fig.suptitle('Latency Results')

sns.lineplot(x='Percentile', y='Latency', data=hgrm_df, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Latency Distribution')
ax.set_xlabel('Percentile (%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Latency (seconds)')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks([1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000])
ax.set_xticklabels(['0', '90', '99', '99.9', '99.99', '99.999', '99.9999', '99.99999'])

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig(png_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

These type of graphs are popular in the low-latency community for plotting latency distributions. When dealing with latencies most of the interesting information tends to be in the higher percentiles, so a logarithmic view tends to work better. I've first seen these graphs used in https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup and https://github.com/HdrHistogram/.

The cited graph was generated by the following code

```
n = ceil(log10(length(values)));          
p = 1 - 1./10.^(0:0.01:n);
percentiles = prctile(values, p * 100);
semilogx(1./(1-p), percentiles);
```

The x-axis was labelled with the code below

```
labels = cell(n+1, 1);
for i = 1:n+1
  labels{i} = getPercentileLabel(i-1);
end
set(gca, 'XTick', 10.^(0:n));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', labels);

% {'0%' '90%' '99%' '99.9%' '99.99%' '99.999%' '99.999%' '99.9999%'}
function label = getPercentileLabel(i)
    switch(i)
        case 0
            label = '0%';
        case 1
            label = '90%';
        case 2
            label = '99%';
        otherwise
            label = '99.';
            for k = 1:i-2
                label = [label '9'];
            end
            label = [label '%'];
    end
end
```

Comment: Florian - Thanks for posting the MATLAB code, I'm sure that will be useful for someone else in the future.  I agree that this kind of scale is much more understandable for data with "high tail" distributions.