# Reverse log axis in Altair

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I am trying to plot [this](http://hdrhistogram.github.io/HdrHistogram/plotFiles.html) type of chart in Altair. Is there an idiomatic way of configuring horizontal axis in such a way that it is logarithmic and "directed from 100 to 0". The idea it that I want to have high resolution of numbers around 100, not around 0.[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072734/percentile-distribution-graph) people are trying to do the same using other plotting libraries.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this directly in the Altair but the post you linked to seems to show how to make the transformation manually and then you could relabel the axis in Altair as needed using `axis=alt.Axis(values=...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `type` parameter in scale [definition](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Scale.html) to achieve this.
If you use `type = "pow"` with a [corresponding](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#pow) `exponent` value, you can flexibly tune X and Y axes:

> `scale=alt.Scale(type="pow", exponent=np.e)`

[image: exp axes]

```py
# Create dummy data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.exponential(1, 100) # Distribution to verify the inverse-log (exp) plot axis
y.sort()

alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y}), title="Exp Axes").transform_window(
    cumulative_sum="sum(y)",
    sort=[{"field": "x"}],
).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("x:Q", scale=alt.Scale(type="pow", exponent=np.e)),
    y=alt.Y("cumulative_sum:Q", scale=alt.Scale(type="pow", exponent=1)),
)
```

As a reference, here's how the raw signal looks like when plotted:

```py
alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y}), title="Raw Plot").transform_window(
    cumulative_sum="sum(y)",
    sort=[{"field": "x"}],
).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("x:Q"),
    y=alt.Y("cumulative_sum:Q"),
)
```

[image: Raw signal]